# links on facebook RSS not working

Tags: php, facebook, hyperlink, rss

I am using Feedwind to get RSS from a facebook page. The problem is that the generated links, when clicked, are not working properly and lead to a blank page if I am not logged on facebook, while if  i am, it ask you to confirm the link to proceed. The generated address is something like this:

```
http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Ftravel%2F2014%2Fapr%2F25%2Fitaly-puglia-salento-region&h=9AQG93jzV&s=1
```

while it should be like this:

```
http://www.theguardian.com/travel/2014/apr/25/italy-puglia-salento-region
```

any thoughts on how to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, that's the way Facebook generates its RSS feeds.  Therefore, the only way to change it is to get the RSS feed data, search it for "http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=", decode the part that follows, and replace the url of the link with the string you just created.

```
$matches = array();
pregmatchall(/http:\/\/l\.facebook\.com\/l\.php\?u=([^"]+)/, $rss, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $index => $match) {
    $url = urldecode(html_entity_decode($matches[1][$index]));
    str_replace($match, $url, $rss);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. how should i implement this code?I am a bit weak on PHP

Comment: It's probably giving on error on line #2 because $rss is not defined.  Since I do not know how your code is written, I cannot guess how you are getting your rss data, so I had to make something up.  So I just used $rss as a theoretical variable that contains your rss data.  You'll have to figure out how to get your rss data into $rss on your own, or post some code.